# Mysql/php select using 2 tables and search information from them

Tags: php, mysql

In my SQL I have 2 tables: `film = filmid, filmname` and `review = id, reviewtitle, filmreview, filmid`.

I basically want to create a form using HTML to search for a `filmname` that is in `film` table, then after doing that I want to retrieve the review from the `review` table where the `filmid` matches with the `film table`, in order to match the `filmname` to the review.

Anyone know to do this? any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
$searching=$_POST['searching'];
$searchfilm=$_POST['searchfilm'];


//This is only displayed if they have submitted the form
if ($searching =="yes")
 {
 echo "<h2>Film Review</h2><p>";


 //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
 if ($searchfilm == "")
 {
 echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term";
 echo
 exit;
 }


 // Otherwise we connect to our Database



 // We preform a bit of filtering
 $searchfilm = strtoupper($searchfilm);
 $searchfilm = strip_tags($searchfilm);
 $searchfilm = trim ($searchfilm);


  //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT filmid, filmname FROM film WHERE filmname LIKE        '$searchfilm'"); WORKS 


 $result = mysql_query($data1) or die(mysql_error()); 


 //results
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data1))
 {
 echo $row['filmid'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo $row['filmname'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo $row['filmreview'];
 echo "<br>";
 }


  //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that
 $anymatches = mysql_num_rows($data1); 
 if ($anymatches == 0)
 {
 echo "Sorry, the film name does not exist<br><br>";
 }


 //what was searched
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$searchfilm;
 }


////////////////////////////

$searchfilm=$_POST['searchfilm'];

/*connect to database*/


/*query database*/
$query = "SELECT review.* FROM film, review where film.filmid=".$searchfilm." AND        film.filmid=review.id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

/*handle result*/
if ($result)
while($reviews_from_db = mysql_fetch_array($result))
/* if reviews_from_db is not null it will contain a multi-dimensional array, with an     element for each review and each of those is an array with the database fields */
{
    echo $row['filmid'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['filmname'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['filmreview'];
    echo "<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what you are asking - are you looking for the SQL, the PHP to call the SQL, or just how to approach the problem?

Assuming you are not using a plain text field in your html form, but instead some form of list that the user selects from and will return the associated film_id,  the PHP & SQLwould be similar to:

```
/*connect to database*/
mysql_connect("hostname","db_user","password") or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db("database_name") or die( "Unable to select database. ".mysql_error());

/*query database*/
$query="SELECT review.* FROM film, review where film.filmid='$film_id_from_html' AND film.filmid=review.filmid";
$result=mysql_query($query);

/*handle result*/
if ($result){
    $reviews_from_db=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    /* if reviews_from_db is not null it will contain a multi-dimensional array, with an element for each review and each of those is an array with the database fields */
}
```

Obviously this requires more work, e.g. it should be broken into functions; I have not included error handling, etc. etc

If you want a plain text field for users to type the film in, you're getting into much more complicated  territory, as user input is unreliable and will need validation - you need to manage differences in punctuation, spelling spaces and even titles (eg "Lord of the Rings", "The Lord of the Rings", "LOTR", "Lord of the Rings, part I" etc are just some possible versions that could be typed in), and on top of that you are also opening the database up to security risks.

**Edit:**
As you want to do a name comparison, this is the query you need:

```
$query="SELECT review.* FROM film, review where film.filmname='$film_name_from_html' AND film.filmid=review.filmid";
```

Comment: what i mean is i will create a search form where you can search for a film thats in the DB and i just want to retrieve the review using the film i searched for

Comment: ok i have kind of figured the searching out but i need 2 select statements 1 for searching for the film name and the second for getting the review any ideas how this should look ? this is what i used to search the film  $data = mysql_query("SELECT filmid, filmname FROM film WHERE filmname LIKE '$searchfilm'");

Comment: You don't need 2 queries, only one with a join. I've already given it to you in the code above.

Comment: FYI, the query I gave you searches by the id instead of the name; to search for the name, syntactically you just replace the id field with the name field. But as I explained, its not as simple as doing a straight comparison on user-submitted text. It is highly unlikely anyone will input text absolutely identical to the db so it will most likely return nothing for most inputs for the reasons I gave above. Is this for a college project? Because it is based on highly flawed logic for a real application.

Comment: yes it is a project that i have to do, how is it flawed ? the point of this is a user searches a film, then the reviews come up then the user can analysis the review using the words in the review to determine whether its positive or negative, my DB contains 2 tables for negative and positive words

Comment: just to clarify will the statement you gave above give the film name and film review when the user searches?

Comment: As this is a college project you're not supposed to be getting someone else to do it for you, so I'll let you figure that out yourself... but think about it, what would you think "SELECT review.*" would return? If you are supposed to be learning SQL you really should know this :-) I've already explained twice why its flawed, I'm sure you don't really need me to explain again?

Comment: Also, as its a college project and you think you need 2 queries maybe you haven't covered joins yet, so in that case maybe you should stick with what you know. In that case $data = mysql_query("SELECT filmid, filmname FROM film WHERE filmname LIKE '$searchfilm'"); is almost correct but LIKE is supposed to use wildcards, but you are not using any. I don't know what you have covered, so you'll have to figure out a way of using the results in a second query... any ideas?

Comment: "great help...."???!! StackOverflow is not meant to get someone to do your project for you!!! But I've already given you the answer TWICE as well as the code - all i'm asking is for you to think about it because you are supposed to be learning from this project!

Comment: i am now looking for the answer but help with it, your answer doesnt really make sense and doesnt seem to work

Comment: You need to give specific details if you need specific help. In what way does it not seem to work?

Comment: i get this error ( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\reviews.php on line 44
for 2 lines of code

Comment: The error message on its own is not enough to see where your problem actually lies - all it tells us is that the parameter you're passing into mysql_fetch_array is not a valid result from mysql_query, its a boolean. Can you also update you original post to include the exact code you are using for the query (no need for the db connection of course)?

Comment: ok its been added at the top, but its what i am currently using

Comment: That is not my code, so its not my code that "doesn't seem to work" :-) You got some basic errors though - I'm going to start a new answer for those

Answer (score 0):

Now we're getting somewhere! You need to give as much information as possible to get specific (and therefore helpful) answers. Now that that you have edited your post to add your code, we can see where you're going wrong. To start with, you have some basic errors before we even get to querying the database.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT filmid, filmname FROM film WHERE filmname LIKE        '$searchfilm'"); 
$result = mysql_query($data1) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){...}
```

1. you have `$data = my_query(...)` but you use `$data1` in the rest of the code
2. You get the result of your query into the variable `$result`, but you pass the string containing your SQL (`$data1`) to mysql_fetch_array()

Other problems:
Technically you shouldn't be using `LIKE` as you are not doing a wildcard search - this is a straight comparison so you should use `=`. (LIKE may work, but its wrong & inefficient here)

**Edit:**
Looking at the new code you added:

```
$query = "SELECT review.* FROM film, review where film.filmid=".$searchfilm." AND        film.filmid=review.id";
$result = mysql_query($query);$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result)
while($reviews_from_db = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['filmid'];
```

1. you are comparing searchfilm to the id instead of filmname: `film.filmid=".$searchfilm`. It should be:

   $query="SELECT review.* FROM film, review where film.filmname=".$searchfilm." AND film.filmid=review.filmid";
2. you save the result row in `$reviews_from_db` but use the wrong variable name `$row` to access the data in it.

Comment: ok thanks for your code this is what i have done but i get a blank page when i search for a film :

Comment: i have pasted it in the edit at the top below the original code

Comment: for some reason i am still getting a blank form when i search not sure if its because of this:
if ($searchfilm == "")
 
  echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term";
 
  else
     while($reviews_from_db = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    /* if reviews_from_db is not null it will contain a multi-dimensional array, with an element for each review and each of those is an array with the database fields */
 {
  echo $reviews_from_db['filmid'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $reviews_from_db['filmname'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $reviews_from_db['filmreview'];
  echo "<br>";
 }

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL directly in the database to see if the problem is with the query or the code? Also, have you debugged the code to make sure everything else is working, e.g. does $searchfilm have the correct value? Does it match EXACTLY the entry in the database? As I said before, even an extra space will cause the comparison to fail. Try just even adding echo statements after each stage to debug it and identify where its failing.

Comment: FYI you should do your check for "" first - otherwise you are adding extra processing by querying the database unnecessarily. It won't stop the code working but it's bad practice.

Comment: seems to me like there is something wrong with the statement because i replaced it with mine and it works fine

Comment: You sorted out the code problems as well then? Sorry, I forgot to include single quotes around the search text, but other than that it's syntactically fine assuming I have the table names and fields correct... you'll need to check those yourself. It should be $query="SELECT review.* FROM film, review where film.filmname='searchfilm' AND film.filmid=review.filmid";

Comment: when i search i keep getting a blank screen just cant find what the problem is

Comment: Its impossible to narrow down the problem without access to your db. The query works directly in the db and you fixed the code errors? Did you get anywhere with the echo statements to track down where the problem lies? If thats all fine, then start by eliminating all possible problems - start a new php file & add the code one part at a time, errorchecking & validating it works properly before adding the next bit. You could start by only including a very simple query e.g. "Select * from film" to eliminate potential problems with the html form, the query itself or the variable being used.

Comment: $query = "SELECT film.filmname, review.filmreview FROM film, review WHERE film.filmid = review.filmid AND filmname = '$searchfilm'"; managed to get it to work using that although searching ect still needs work